# why does changing the group of my /home folder affects what happens in a subdirectory

Tags: permissions, directory

There is a fundamental aspect of the way permissions work in linux directories I think I have not understood.

I have this folder I was trying to access from my local apache server :

```
sudo chmod 777 /home/ut/programmes/Programmation/p5-linux/
sudo -u www-data ls /home/ut/programmes/Programmation/p5-linux/
ls: cannot read directory '/home/ut/programmes/Programmation/p5-linux/': Permission denied
```

**Why is it not working ? even though the permission is 777 ?**

Moreover, by doing :

```
sudo chown ut:www-data /home/ut
sudo chmod 710 /home/ut
```

without changing anything to the permission in /home/ut/programmes/Programmation/p5-linux/, now this is what I get :

```
sudo -u www-data ls /home/ut/programmes/Programmation/p5-linux/
icudtl.dat  libffmpegsumo.so  locales  nw.pak  p5  p5.png  Projets
```

the only thing I did was to change the group of a parent dictory.
**why does it work now ?**

Answer (score 0):

On your first try you have all permissions to the last directory only:

```
/home/ut/programmes/Programmation/p5-linux/
```

But you need to have "execution" permission to all parent directories. From what you add, we understand that you dont have execute on /home/ut. Note that you dont need to have read permission to parent directories.

In your second try you have found that you need only execute permission (and not read)